# Google Script - Get Google Drive Link to Sheet on custom form submit (file upload field)

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-forms

I am new on Google Scripts. I am trying to retrieve the uploaded Google Drive's file link to the Sheet upon form submission, on a custom Google Form. However on form submit, only the file name is added to the sheet. Is there a way to get the file's Google Drive link to the sheet on form submit?

Here's what I have so far:

> Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>

<form id="form" action="https://docs.google.com/forms/u/0/d/e/####/formResponse" method="POST">
  <div class="file-field input-field">
    <input type="file" id="uploadfile" name="file">
    <input id="upload_MC" name="entry.685812703" class="file-path validate" type="text" placeholder="Upload MC or other reference if applicable" onchange="uploadMC()">
  </div>
  
  <input id="submit" type="submit"/>
</form>

<script>
  function uploadMC(){
    const file = form.file.files[0];
    const fr = new FileReader();
    fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    fr.onload = (f) => {
      const url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/###/exec"; //the URL of Web Apps.

      const qs = new URLSearchParams({
        filename: file.name,
        mimeType: file.type,
      });
      fetch(`${url}?${qs}`, {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify([...new Int8Array(f.target.result)]),
      })
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(console.log)
        .catch(console.log);
    };
  }
</script>

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

> Code.gs

```
function doGet(e){
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page").evaluate().addMetaTag("viewport", "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0");
}

function doPost(e) {
  const folderId = "###"; // Folder ID which is used for putting the file.

  const blob = Utilities.newBlob(
    JSON.parse(e.postData.contents),
    e.parameter.mimeType,
    e.parameter.filename
  );
  const file = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId || "root").createFile(blob);
  const responseObj = file.getUrl();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify(responseObj)
  ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

The **page.html** is my custom Google Form that sends the data to the linked Sheet. Right now it does upload the file and the file name are submitted in the Sheet, but is there a way to get the file's viewing link to be inserted into the Sheet instead of the file's name?

Thank you in advance and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url to the file is returned by `Code.gs`

```
  const responseObj = file.getUrl();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(
    JSON.stringify(responseObj)
  ).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

1. Add the url field to both your custom Google Form and the original Google Form.

```
<input id="uploadUrl" type="hidden" name="entry.XXX">
```

2. Modify the function to pass the url to the input field

```
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then(json => {
          console.log(json);
          uploadUrl.value = JSON.stringify(json);
        })
        .catch(console.log);
```